# An openGLES program encounter an error on Android 4.4 but works on 4.1, why?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The OpenGLES program encounter an error on Android 4.4:

```
09-20 21:14:16.695 I/dalvikvm(16504): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9... 
09-20 21:14:16.755 I/Process (16480): Sending signal. PID: 16480 SIG: 9
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466): GLUseful failed to compile shader source:
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466): precision mediump float;
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466): #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466): uniform samplerExternalOES view_image;
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466): varying vec2 image_coord;
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466): void main()
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466):   {
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466):     gl_FragColor = texture2D(view_image, image_coord);
09-20 21:14:16.760 W/System.err(16466):   }/*main*/
09-20 21:14:16.765 W/dalvikvm(16466): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41628c50)
```

But the same APK can run on Android 4.1 without any error, why?

Comment: Is the `GL_OES_EGL_image_external` extension supported on the 4.4 device you're testing?

Comment: I think you are focusing on the wrong thing here. Android 4.1 to 4.4 is probably the least significant change, more than likely you're dealing with two different devices and different implementations of OpenGL ES (with different capabilities).

Comment: @RetoKoradi How to check whether GL_OES_EGL_image_external extension is supported?